# polymer error on reloading

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

i have installed the polymer starter kit and once i load the starter kit every thing gets loaded properly and the url looks like http://127.0.0.1:8887/ then once i click on any view that page gets open and url changes to http://127.0.0.1:8887/view1 but if i reload the browser now, instead of showing the same page it displays the entry not found error.i have tried searching over internet for solution but i didn't find one.what should i do to fix it.

Comment: Are you using the `polymer serve` command from the Polymer CLI or other web server?

Comment: im using chrome web server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you refresh the page (http://127.0.0.1:8887/view1) you request the `view1` resource from the server, but the server can't find it because there isn't. That path (`.../view1`) is only recognized by the polymer app itself and not the server.

Try using hash in the path. Add the `use-hash-as-path` attribute to your `app-location` element inside the main page.

So, it should look like this:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
```

**EDIT**

It is not enough to add the `use-hash-as-path` property. You will also need to change slightly the `href` in the menu items.

`href="/view1"` to `href="#/view1"`

The code with more details:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>

  <!-- Drawer content -->
  <app-drawer>
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="view1" href="#/view1">View One</a>
      <a name="view2" href="#/view2">View Two</a>
      <a name="view3" href="#/view3">View Three</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>
  ...
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Comment: Edited my answer because the explanation wasn't entirely correct, the solution remains the same.

Comment: do i need to link any components to th page??

Comment: Could you share your `my-app.html` and `my-view1.html`? You can use [gist](https://gist.github.com/) for example. It is hard to locate the problem without seeing any code.

Comment: I am really sorry, I forgot to mention to change the `href` also in the menu items. I edited the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123934/discussion-between-aries12-and-hunex).