# Polymer starter-kit navigation by url broken, but only when deployed

Tags: polymer-starter-kit

Navigation by url to my polymerCLI generated starter-kit works perfectly deployed locally by ">polymer serve", but navigation by url is broken when deployed to an https site.

Entire generated app untouched is on github at https://github.com/datafundamentals/polymer1-starter-debug
README describes exact details.

Entire built and deployed starter-kit untouched is at https://cliffdweller.work/view1 but emptying cache and hard reload may be necessary to display 404 if you nav by menu first.

Really hope that I just haven't skipped some docs somewhere but if so, I'm sure I'll get the flames I deserve. I've been scratching my head on how to even look it up?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was posted [polymer error on reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608956/polymer-error-on-reload%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bing)

There are two fixes required, both the use-hash-as-path property and the use of the #/ as a prefix, so a quick glance at this answer may not be sufficient.