# Hosting Polymer app on web server with base URLs

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, relative-path, polymer-starter-kit

If I take the [Polymer starter kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/), it works well locally.
I can navigate to http://localhost:8080/ and all the links to the 3 views work fine.

Now, if I host this app on a web server (that is shared with other apps) on a URL such as http://myservername:8080/mywonderfulapp/, I am having trouble with the routing. Is there a way I can mention the app-route to take in the relative URL?

I tried making changes to the html files to have relative URLs

```
<link rel="import" href="./src/my-app.html">
<a name="view1" href="./view1">View One</a>
<base href="/mywonderfulapp/">
```

but I cant seem to fix the app-routing in a similar fashion.

All similar questions here on SO seem to be about a pre-1.0 version of Polymer, and mention page.js and hash-bang routing instead of the HTML5-history-friendly URLs and the app-route component.

I would prefer to make minimal code changes to ensure

- the same code works locally as well as on the remote host
- the app is not dependent on the base URL on which it is hosted - so, preferably I dont have to mention "mywonderfulapp" (from the URL above) anywhere in the code.

Comment: I think you're running onto this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608956/polymer-error-on-reloading

Comment: No, that's a different issue. In that one, it requires server-side routing to map certain URLs to index.html.

Comment: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/commit/7082366bc258ae748837d3adfe754e70955180f9   that may be relevant to the routing/ page.js issue you have

Comment: Thanks Robert. That commit is not relevant now, as Polymer isn't using page.js for routing anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I got with this so far, is to:

mention a placeholder for a URL prefix in the app-route pattern.

```
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:prefix/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
```

and then use that in the `href` attribute for the anchor

```
<a name="view1" href="/[[routeData.prefix]]/view1">View One</a>
<a name="view2" href="/[[routeData.prefix]]/view2">View Two</a>
<a name="view3" href="/[[routeData.prefix]]/view3">View Three</a>
```

The drawback with this approach is that I have to use the URL as http://localhost:8080/mywonderfulapp/ even when working locally, but at least I don't have to modify code anymore when deploying to my remote web server.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, until a better answer emerges.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this was solved in a similar posting on stackoverflow.com/questions/39608956/polymer-error-on-reload‌​ing

Side note for firebase users - if you deploy this same version of starter kit to firebase and do a firebase serve at the CLI, this problem will even occur in the localhost, so you will need the above fix, even for there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But again, as stated in response to that comment you mention, this is not the same issue. In the other case, the 404 happens when the user attempts to go directly to a specific URL, which requires some server-side routing to map the requested URL to index.html so that Polymer can then do its routing on the client-side. In my case, I start with the home page, and when I attempt to navigate to the other views by clicking on the links, I get a 404 due to wrong path for the html files. It seems to me that the app-route and related JS code needs to be aware of my base URL.