# Polymer app not loading when using Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, polymer

I have a Polymer app running on port 5901 of my VM, and am using Apache reverse proxy to serve the app from the following URL:

http://www.example.com/polymer

The problem is when I go to the URL in a browser, I can see the page title but the page is blank. I also get this error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   src/home-page.html
```

I'm assuming that I have to somehow add the /polymer subdomain to the default URL for the app, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Could it not be an Apache error in proxying?

Comment: I don't think so, because I had the same issue when trying to run a React app. In that case I just had to update the URLs for the app to include /react, but I am not sure how to do that in Polymer.

Comment: See my answer below.  Hope it helps.

Comment: so is there a home-page.html inside src ?
post your index.html and specifically the base href.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: In response to comment:

The relevant link for Polymer 2.0 routing is https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/routing .

> Updating the route. The route object is read-write, so you can use two-way data binding or this.set to update the route. Both the route and routeData objects can be manipulated this way. For example:

```
this.set('route.path', '/search/');
```

> Or:

```
this.set('routeData.user', 'mary');
```

Comment: Looks like this is from Polymer 1.0, my app is using app-route instead of page.js for routing so I don't think this will work for me..

Comment: Do you know where I would put that code? I can't tell from the documentation

Comment: What is the directory and file structure of your project (pls append to qn)?

Comment: I got it working based on this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804737/hosting-polymer-app-on-web-server-with-base-urls?rq=1), thanks for your help.